get() of a computed property never gets invoked
i am using vue3 with options api
as shown in the below posted code, i have two radio buttons, the first one will invoke onShowGeoTIFFOverlayChanged and the second one will invoke onHideGeoTIFFOverlayChanged when pressed.
when i press the the first one, onShowGeoTIFFOverlayChanged gets called and consequently compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1 gets called and the get() and set() gets called accordingly.
the problem is when i press the second button, it will result in calling onHideGeoTIFFOverlayChanged then the set() method gets called but the get() method never gets invoked.
please let me know why that is happening and how to solve it
update
what i am trying to do is, when the first radio button is pressed,i want to signalize that it is pressed and the other is not. and when i press the second radio button, i want to segnalize that the second one is pressed while the first is not.
how can i achieve that please? also the approach i adopted in my question works for the first radio button but not for the second.
<template>
    <cds-radio id="idRadioBtnShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1Container">
        <label id="idTextOnGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1">{{ tempTextOn }}</label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            :value="compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1', $event.target.value)"
            :disabled="isRadioButtonShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1Disabled"
            :checked="isCheckedRadioButtonShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1"
            @change="onShowGeoTIFFOverlayChanged()"
        />
    </cds-radio>

    <cds-radio id="idRadioBtnHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1Container">
        <label id="idTextOffGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1">{{ tempTextOff }}</label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            :value="compPropsVModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1', $event.target.value)"
            :disabled="isRadioButtonHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1Disabled"
            :checked="isCheckedRadioButtonHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1"
            @change="onHideGeoTIFFOverlayChanged()"
        />
    </cds-radio>
</template>

props: {
    vModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1: {
        type: Boolean,
        type: null,
    },
    vModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1: {
        type: Boolean,
        type: null,
    },
},
emits: {
    'update:vModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1': null,
    'update:vModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1': null,
},
computed: {
    compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1: {
        get() {
            console.log('xcx get.compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1:', this.vModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1);
            return this.vModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1;
        },
        set(value) {
            console.log('xcx set.compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1:', value);
            this.$emit('update:vModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1', value);
        },
    },
    compPropsVModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1: {
        get() {
            console.log('xcx get.compPropsVModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1:', this.vModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1);
            return this.vModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1;
        },
        set(value) {
            console.log('xcx set.compPropsVModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1:', value);
            this.$emit('update:vModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1', value);
        },
    },
},
methods: {
    async onShowGeoTIFFOverlayChanged() {
        msg = JSON.stringify({msg:verboseTag + '@watch xcx onShowGeoTIFFOverlayChanged.'});
        console.log(msg);
        this.compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1 = true;
        this.compPropsVModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1 = false;
        
        await this.refStoreOnRadioButtonShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.actions.init();
        this.refStoreOnRadioButtonShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.setters.set(true);
        await this.refStoreOnRadioButtonHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.actions.init();
        this.refStoreOnRadioButtonHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.setters.set(false);
    },
    async onHideGeoTIFFOverlayChanged() {
        msg = JSON.stringify({msg:verboseTag + '@watch xcx onHideGeoTIFFOverlayChanged.'});
        console.log(msg);
        this.compPropsVModelShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1 = false;
        this.compPropsVModelHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1 = true;
        
        await this.refStoreOnRadioButtonShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.actions.init();
        this.refStoreOnRadioButtonShowGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.setters.set(false);
        await this.refStoreOnRadioButtonHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.actions.init();
        this.refStoreOnRadioButtonHideGeoTIFFOverlayForTS1.setters.set(true);
    },
}


This looks like XY problem if the purpose of = true + = false is to trigger an update through reactivity. This can result in no update if computed value stays the same

@EstusFlask thank you for your attention.please have a look at the update section posted above

@EstusFlask i also adapted the code, please notice the methods: { .... }  section of the code. do you think the way i used to signalize the buttons being pressed with Store is valid?
